# PluginVersionResolutionException in Maven project when I set packaging to bundle

Tags: maven, apache-felix

In my Maven project when I change the packaging type from 'jar' to 'bundle' most of my plugins (compiler, deploy, install, resources, surefire) lose their versions. Why is this?

My pom.xml is below:

```
<groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
<artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.ui_4.4.35_patch</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Name>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
                    <Export-Package>web.admin.*</Export-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Simply because they are not bound to that life cycle... https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.2/maven-core/default-bindings.html

Comment: Thanks for your response, in that case is "<packaging>bundle</packaging>" invalid? I need a jar file so perhaps I can remove this line

Comment: If you like to get a jar file you should use `jar` and can make an supplemental execution with bundle plugin to get OSGi information into your manifest file.

Comment: At the moment I type 'mvn clean install' which generates the jar. How do I make that 
supplemental execution? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible approaches. The one I use for my own projects is to keep the `bundle` packaging and add the maven plugin versions to a `pluginManagement` section in the pom.xml. For example:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <!-- Add you current 'plugins' section here. -->
</build>
```

In addition to the version, you can also add `configuration` to each plugin. If your project has a parent pom, it would be natural to add the `pluginManagement` section there instead of in your bundle module.

Alternatively, as suggested by @khmarbaise, you can use `jar` packaging and just use the maven-bundle-plugin to generate the manifest. That approach is described in the [plugin documentation page](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#adding-osgi-metadata-to-existing-projects-without-changing-the-packaging-type).

Comment: Thanks @gjoranv, I used the same approach as you and got it working